# Get the attention vector from the last layers of BERT

Tags: text, nlp, bert-language-model

Is there any way to get the attention vector with normalizing values (0-1) from the last layer of BERT? I'm interested in getting the attention value that BERT assigns to each word in a sentence.

I'm working on emotion classification. I want to extract the relevant words associated with emotions. For example:

I feel wonderful today.

The words feel and wonderful are the more relevant words in the sentence for the classifier, so I want to get the attention scores that BERT assigns to each of them.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you post an example of what you want? Also, could you post what you have tried so far?

Comment: Yes of course, I have edited the question. I did emotion classification with BERT but I don't know how to extract the attention values.